Usage of "the" article in place names containing city or town names
I am confused if I should use the article "the" before a place name containing the city or town name (in the example below, "Silang" is the town name):

Our Lady of Candelaria Parish Church, commonly known as the Silang Church, is ...

vs.

Our Lady of Candelaria Parish Church, commonly known as Silang Church, is ...

I am inclined to use the latter sentence, but I am unsure which should be used.

I don't think there's a formal rule, but the parish church of a locality is normally referred to as '[Name] Church' without the article. Similarly, '[Name] University', but 'The University of [Name]'. I'm sure there are exceptions, though.

There are a couple of related questions like this one about "the" with various London place names. Not a clear-cut answer though: do what others do.

You should probably mention your source, which I assume is this Wikipedia article about the church.

The word 'church' is usually applied to a single building/congregation when not speaking about the universal Church [see article at The Gospel Coalition].  If there is only one such in say Elboniaton, it might be referred to as 'the Elboniaton church' (and even capitalised). But it would have to be a remarkable building to be referred to that way if there were other churches in Elboniaton. Individual churches are often named, as with 'St Ebbe's Church, Elboniaton' or 'the Church of St Ebbe's, Elboniaton' or ...

just 'St Ebbe's, Elboniaton'. And if the location is known or obvious, the name of the settlement is usually dropped, thus 'St Ebbe's'. /// As for the Wikipedia article: 'Diocesan Shrine and Parish of Our Lady of Candelaria' needs a definite article except in headlinese, while  'Silang Church' would sound unidiomatic with one.

Whether to use "the" in place names is ideosyncratic. There are some common styles, but no overall rule.

I feel like the pattern here is "the + [city name] + [common noun] = [proper noun reference]," and it works with many things besides churches. The Paris Metro, the London Eye. But cf "Boston Harbor": typically zero article. So... this pattern usually takes "the," but there are exceptions?
